# troubles configuring nginx to serve HTTP and HTTPS sites from a single server

Tags: http, nginx, https, virtualhost

I have a single server that hosts few websites;
to reduce the problem let's assume they are just two:
`http://www.example-A.com`
`https://www.example-B.com`

Site `A` offers only HTTP connections while site `B` has its own SSL certificate and offers secure connections.

My config file looks like this (relevant part):

```
http
{
    server
    {
        listen 80;

        server_name www.example-A.com;

        [...]
    }

    server
    {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example-B.com;
        return 301 https://www.example-B.com$request_uri;
    }

    server
    {
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/ssl/www.exampe-A.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/ssl/www.exampe-A.com.key;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        server_name www.example-B.com;

        [...]
    }
}
```

Now if I connect to `http://www.example-A.com` everything works fine.
Also connecting to `https://www.example-B.com` works as expected.
Connecting to `http://www.example-B.com` results in a redirect to `https://www.example-B.com`

So far so good.

Now the problem arirses if I try a secure connection to `A`: `https://www.example-A.com`

I would expect the server to refuse the connection.

What I get instead is that the browser warns that the connection is not secure.
As I proceed I land on the domain `https://www.example-A.com` but the content of `www.example-B.com` is served.

If I add to the configuration

```
    server
    {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name www.example-A.com;

        return 444;
    }
```

Then attempting a secure connection to `A` fails as expected.

But also connecting to `https://www.example-B.com` fails.

---

What am I missing? Why `server_name` directive is not respected?

How can I serve `A` in HTTP, `B` in HTTPS and block unsupported HTTPS connections to `A`?

---

I am running

```
$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.12.2
built with OpenSSL 1.1.0d  26 Jan 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/local --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/usr/local/nginx/nginx.conf --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-pcre=../pcre-8.37 --add-module=../headers-more-nginx-module-0.33
```

Answer (score 0):

A best practice is to have a `default_server`, this directive specifies to use **this** server if the hostname is not known, you can use this as a catch-all to handle any hostnames that do not match your `server_name` value. Without this the first server is treated as the default

e.g.

```
# 444 Close connection Without Response on requests without hostname
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name _;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl/example.com.key;
    return 444;
}
```

Comment: if I add this `server` block then connections to `www.example-b.com` fail

Comment: your redirect should include the `.com` right? i.e. `https://www.example-b.com$request_uri;`